# why i can't execute the procedure in shell script

Tags: oracle, shell, concurrency, plsql

i have the following code inside a shell script .prog in oracle server
when i call the program

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x_return_status|| ln_rep_req_id);
```

will return 0  , it is very strange , i try to submit the concurrent request in oracle , and it can successfully executed, what am i missing ? i can't get it working in the shell script.

```
echo "1_FILE_NAME_String:"${DOWNLOADFILE}";2_USER_ID_String:"${2}";3_FILE_ID_String:"${ln_group_id}";4_REQUEST_ID_String:"${4}
sqlplus $LOGIN <<ENDOFSQL
 connect $LOGIN
     SET SERVEROUTPUT ON                                
DECLARE
ld_int_date date;   
P_ERRBUFF VARCHAR2(4000);
   P_ERRCODE VARCHAR2(100);
   P_FILE_NAME VARCHAR2(250);
   P_REQUEST_ID VARCHAR2(100);
   P_ERROR_CODE VARCHAR2(100);
   x_return_status VARCHAR2 (3000);
   ln_rep_req_id NUMBER;

BEGIN
 P_FILE_NAME := '${DOWNLOADFILE}';
   P_REQUEST_ID := TO_CHAR(${4});
   P_ERROR_CODE := 'ERR_003_Incorrect_file_format';

 ln_rep_req_id:= fnd_request.submit_request(application => 'XXGL',
                                                          program     => 'XXGL_PRCERP_INT_BAD',
                                                          description => NULL,
                                                          start_time  => NULL,
                                                          sub_request => FALSE,
                                                          argument1   => P_FILE_NAME,
                                                          argument2   => P_REQUEST_ID,
                                                          argument3   => P_ERROR_CODE
                                                          );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x_return_status|| ln_rep_req_id); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x_return_status|| P_FILE_NAME); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x_return_status|| P_REQUEST_ID); 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x_return_status|| P_ERROR_CODE);
 END;
/

exit
ENDOFSQL
```

Comment: You get an error while running from UNIX ?

Comment: no,i created a concurrent job calling the .prog host file in oracle server, and i was able to control the output status of the job, but it seems that the package procedure that fnd_request.submit_request return is always 0 , i've tried XXGL_INT_GIFPE_PKG.XXGL_LOAD_BAD(
   P_ERRBUFF,
   P_ERRCODE,
   P_FILE_NAME,
   P_REQUEST_ID,
   P_ERROR_CODE
 );  but it also runned the procedure but not executing the content of the procedure.

Comment: i have another part calling procedure like the part i created above and it is working, the part i added is trying to copy the existing syntax, i can return teh result i want when i run the concurrent job in oracle but i failed using shell script.

Answer (score 1):

If `FND_REQUEST.SUBMIT_REQUEST` returns a zero it means that an error occurred. To find out what the error(s) are you'll need to call `FND_MESSAGE.RETRIEVE` and `FND_MESSAGE.ERROR` to retrieve, format, and display the errors.

[Documentation for `FND_REQUEST.SUBMIT_REQUEST` here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T458258.htm).

[Documentation for `FND_MESSAGE.RETRIEVE` and `FND_MESSAGE.ERROR` here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T462354.htm).

Share and enjoy.

Comment: i added DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x_return_status|| v_msg);   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x_return_status|| v_msg);   and it return  '
FND CONC-Failed to get oracle name
'

Answer (score 0):

i have forgotten to include the following in my procedure, so it cannot be run. thanks for all of your help.

> fnd_global.apps_initialize(user_id      => lc_user_id,
>                                    resp_id      => ln_resp_id,
>                                    resp_appl_id => ln_appl_id);